# Android studio - some of the interpolator animations not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, crash

I am trying to apply animations to my project, when I set the interpolator to:

alpha.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">

    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:duration="4000"
        />

</set>
```

SplashActivity.java:

```
package com.example.animationtesting;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    Animation alpha;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        alpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.alpha);
        imageView.setAnimation(alpha);
        textView.setAnimation(alpha);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },4000);


    }
}
```

Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AnimationTesting"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The code is working fine when I set the interpolator as bounce_interpolator, accelerate_interpolator, anticipate_overshoot_interpolator but when I set the interpolator to other options like fade_in, fade_out,slide_out_right my app crashes. I don't get why this is happening.

Comment: Where are you applying your animations? Are you applying _all of them_ them via code? Some animations have to be set in the nav_graph.xml. (Like the slide_out_right, if it's a transition between fragments).

Comment: I am creating a splash activity, there i'm using the animations. Kindly check my updated code. And could you please tell me about the nav_graph.xml in detail. Thank you.

Comment: I can't really explain it that well in a comment, but technically, the `nav_graph.xml` is just a file, where one can declare fragments and `<actions />` (paths to other fragments declared in that file). These paths can be used via their ID in the `findNavController().navigate(...)` to load other fragments into the current context: [More detailed documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

Comment: Something just got into my mind, so I can improve my answer: Can you provide your Manifest?

Comment: I don't really get what I have to do, and here I have updated the Manifest file.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer and thx for the manifest file, but it looks fine. Could you maybe specify on the error you're getting? (If you're not seeing anything in the "run" window, just restart the app till you see something).

Comment: My app is crashing, that's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251716/discussion-between-z-100-and-deepak-bhatt).

Answer (score 0):

First I thought your app crashed because you try to put the animation on two different xml-objects, but then I replicated the entire thing using [this guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-an-animated-splash-screen-in-android/) and for me, everything is working. (Although I did it using Kotlin).

I'm sorry, the only solution I could provide was this URL to the guide, but if you have any more questions, feel free to ask!